# How do I display the output of a string in JSF correctly?

Tags: jsf

I have a string in a Managed Bean that I am returning to JSF as output. The returned string is set to output each String component that it consists of on a new line. However, when I pass it to JSF the string prints all on one line. Is there a way to get around this without having to create an individual method (and returned string) for each of the strings that I have combined in the String 'output'?

```
    public String welcomeDisplay() {
    factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
    EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();   


    if(true){
        em.getTransaction().begin();

        String sessionEmail=Util.getEmail();
        Query myQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM BusinessAccount u WHERE u.email=:email");
        myQuery.setParameter("email", sessionEmail);
        List<BusinessAccount> userList=myQuery.getResultList();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();

        String bName=userList.get(0).getBusinessName();
        String bAddress1=userList.get(0).getAddress1();
        String bAddress2=userList.get(0).getAddress2();
        String bTown=userList.get(0).getTown();
        String bPhone=userList.get(0).getTelephoneNum();
        String bEmail=userList.get(0).getEmail();

        String output=(bName+"\n"+bAddress1+"\n"+bAddress2+"\n"+bTown+"\n"+bPhone+"\n"+bEmail);

        return output;
    } 


    else {
        addMessage(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                "User Registration Failed!", null));
        return "failure";
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<head>
<title>Greeting Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h:form id="greetingForm">
    <H2>Greeting Page</H2>
    <H4>
        <h:outputText value="#{registerBean.welcomeDisplay()}"/>
        ! You have been successfully authenticated.
    </H4>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td><h:outputLabel for="companyDescription">
                    <h:outputText id="descriptionLabel" value="Company Description" />
                </h:outputLabel></td>
        <td><h:inputTextarea rows="10" id="companyDescription" value="#{registerBean.businessAccount.description}"
                    size="20" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><h:commandButton id="createAccounts"
                    action="#{registerBean.update}" value="Update Profile">
                </h:commandButton></td>
        </tr>
                    <tr>
    <td><h:commandButton id="logout" action="#{loginBean.logout}">
        <h:outputText value="Logout" />
    </h:commandButton></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I think you should rethink your design (separate JSF Managed Beans from your business and DAO layers).
To display the String like you want it, just use `<br/>` instead of `\n`. And in your xhtml page:

```
<h:outputText value="#{yourManagedBean.aPrpoerty}" escape="false"/>
```

Where `aPrpoerty` is a String attribute of your managed bean that you set value in the `welcomeDisplay` method and have a getter for it.